# While loop function will not output on JupyterLab immediately following another index/while function

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, indexing, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python taking an academic college course with a lackluster professor. Please help.

Assignment states **Using the while loop***

List all the presidents whose names contain the letter 'o'
List all the presidents whose names do not contain the letter 'w'
For each president, list the number of times the letter 'o' appears

My code:

```
listUSPresidents=["George Washington","John Adams","Thomas Jefferson","James Madison","James Monroe","John Quincy Adams","Andrew Jackson","Martin Van Buren","William H. Harrison","John Tyler","James K. Polk","Zachary Taylor","Millard Fillmore","Franklin Pierce","James Buchanan","Abraham Lincoln","Andrew Johnson","Ulysses S. Grant","Rutherford B. Hayes","James A. Garfield","Chester A. Arthur","Grover Cleveland","Benjamin Harrison","Grover Cleveland","William McKinley","Theodore Roosevelt","William H. Taft","Woodrow Wilson","Warren G. Harding","Calvin Coolidge","Herbert Hoover","Franklin D. Roosevelt","Harry S. Truman","Dwight D. Eisenhower","John F. Kennedy","Lyndon B. Johnson","Richard M. Nixon","Gerald R. Ford","Jimmy Carter","Ronald Reagan","George H. W. Bush","Bill Clinton","George W. Bush","Barack Hussein Obama","Donald J. Trump"]
```

```
## List all the presidents whose names contain the letter 'o'
index = 0
while index < len(listUSPresidents):
    USPresident = listUSPresidents[index]
    if 'o' in USPresident.lower():
        print (USPresident)
        index +=1
```

Returns:
George Washington
John Adams
Thomas Jefferson
James Madison
James Monroe
John Quincy Adams
Andrew Jackson

```
##List all the presidents whose names do not contain the letter 'w'
index = 0
while index < len(listUSPresidents):
    president = listUSPresidents[index]
    if ('w' not in president.lower()):
        print (president)
        index +=1
```

Upon attempting to run the function it immediately skips to the next cell and doesn't run. Same for the next function.

```
## For each president, list the number of times the letter 'o' appears
index = 0
while index != len(listUSPresidents):
    USPresident = listUSPresidents[index]
    O_count = USPresident.lower().count('o')
    print (USPresident, " ", O_count)
    index +=1
```

I tried moving the index outside of the if loop, and it only produces "George Washington" infinitely.

I previously used the same variable "US President" for both but I tried changing the second function to the variable "president" instead but it did not change anything.

I tried creating a second identical list with a different name and it also did not work.

I tried messaging the professor who gave me the following code which also didn't work:

```
#List all the presidents whose names do not contain the letter 'w'
counter = 0
while counter < len(listUSPresidents):
if listUSPresidents[counter].count("w")==0:
print(listUSPresidents[counter])
counter +=1
```

Comment: Your first block of code only increases the index when the `if` condition matches. This means it will keep running the `while` loop infinitely while index doesn't change. That cell might still be running, which would explain while the others are hung. Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: Yes. If I restart the kernel and skip running that cell I run the cell that defines the list first, then I run the second block of code for presidents whose names do not contain "w" and it again doesn't output anything. What you're saying makes sense although I'm not sure how to bypass it.

Comment: The problem is having `index +=1` indented inside the `if`. This means you only increment it under certain conditions. When you don't increment it, nothing changes and the loop goes around again…and agin. This is the case with both of the `'o'` and `'w'` code blocks.

Comment: place the `index += 1` line outside of if condtion

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how indentation in python works.
For example, consider the C/C++ code snippet to print "a" 5 times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout<<"a"<<endl;
}
```

OR

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout<<"a"<<endl;
}
```

OR

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) cout<<"a"<<endl;
```

All of them work the same. The braces define the scope of the loop.

In python, the indentation defines the scope of each loop/conditional statement.
To print "a" 5 times, you need to write

```
i=0
for i < 5:
    print("a")
    i+=1
```

This snippet runs the statement `print("a")` and `i+=1` till `i` becomes 5.
On the other hand,

```
i=0
for i < 5:
    print("a")
i+=1
```

Infinitely prints "a" because the line `i+=1` is never ran inside the for loop and `i<5` always remain true and thus printing "a" forever.

Let's do a small exercise of finding even numbers in a list of numbers. This will explain the whole concept to you.

```
Numbers = [4, 5, 8, 20, 24, 35, 54, 65, 37, 90]
countEven = 0 # initialize the counter to 0
#start the for loop with starting index to be 0
index = 0
for i < len(Numbers):
    #The below code needs to be indented once so that it runs along with loop
    if Numbers[index] % 2 == 0 :#check if the number at index position is even
        #again indent once, to go within the scope of if statement
        countEven += 1
    #This below statement should be written NOT in scope of if statement
    #because index needs to be incremented even if the number is not even
    #if written inside the above if block then it will always be stuck at first
    #odd number it encounters because then if condition will always be false
    #and index variable will never increment
    index += 1
```

The same thing needs to be applied to filter out the names containing "o" and the other exercise.